# Why my layout shrinks while in viewpager but looks fine in the separate layout xml?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

I am using a fragment in a viewpager and when i run it on emulator/device it shrinks and certain text views disappear. But when i view the resource layout of the fragment separately then it just looks fine

**This is how it looks while running on emulator/device : Activity**
[image]

Layout of activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/activity_landing_page"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        tools:context="com.thebitshoes.uocn.AdminHome"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="3">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="326dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/admin_bg_pic"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/profile_icon"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="23dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:background="#737D8C">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="#bfd919"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="40"
                    android:background="#3c424c"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/message_icon"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:src="@mipmap/message_icon_new" />
                <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/notification_icon"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:src="@mipmap/notification_icon" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="57.93"
        android:background="#737d8c"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
                <LinearLayout
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                                    >
                    <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Welcome Back, John Doe !"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2.1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_color_selector"
        app:tabTextColor="#3C424D"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Below is the layout of the fragment as viewed separately, Fragment XML**

[image]

Layout of Fragment used in viewpager

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.18"
        android:background="@drawable/cards"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/student_icon" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="STUDENTS"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="30 admissions in the past 10 days" />
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:text="Total"
                        android:layout_marginTop="6dp" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="100"
                        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.18"
        android:background="@drawable/cards"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/books_icon" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="COURSES"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="252dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="12 course updates 2 months" />
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:text="Total"
                        android:layout_marginTop="6dp" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="100"
                        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.18"
        android:background="@drawable/cards"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/parent_icon" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="PARENTS"
                android:textStyle="bold"

                android:textSize="18sp" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="10 records added yesterday" />
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:text="Total"
                        android:layout_marginTop="6dp" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="200"
                        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.18"
        android:background="@drawable/cards"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/teacher_icon" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TEACHERS"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="10 active teachers"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    />
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:text="Total"
                        android:layout_marginTop="6dp" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="10"
                        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I saw a `LinearLayout` with weight `android:layout_weight="57.93"` in your activity layout xml !!

Comment: hey there.. I was trying to balance it using the GUI of the design view of the layout .While doing it manually, it seems that the value somehow got increased so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you use weight for height of each child LinearLayout? When you put the fragment to your viewpager, it will be resized based on weight ratio. It is because the viewpager does not have enough height.

If you want to show your fragment inside of viewpager same as independent view, you might need to use Scrollview or Listview for the fragment. And you should remove all weight values and make it as wrap_content for each child LinearLayout.

Comment: Initially , i started off making the layout first and that's why i added weights . Was not aware of the effects of it . Thanks for your suggestion . I'll try to redo it using a scroll view

Comment: In this case , will list view be a better option?

Comment: If you are okay it can be scrollable, Scrollview will be easy to fix based on your code. And If you are willing to add more items in the future, I would recommend ListView or RecyclerView with adapter.

Comment: However, if you want fixed size view rather than scrollable design, just make it with smaller fixed height.

Comment: i have only these 4 details to show on cards, namely : Students,Courses,Parents,Teachers

Comment: Then just change height as wrap_content  and make each component item smaller to be shown in a page.

Comment: I actually want it to be fixed. Nothing more is getting addd below 'Teachers'. I was trying to make the same using the layout as in the post above but all i was getting is shrinked layout. Should i remove weights if i dont want to scroll view or list view?

Comment: Yes, if you want it to be fixed you should remove all the weight values.